# How do you integrate the java annotation processor into the java plugin

Tags: java, hibernate, gradle

I have a project that is laid out as follows:

```
src/
  java
  generated
```

src/java contains jpa entities and query classes that use the jpa metamodel classes that are generated by the [hibernate metamodel annotation processor](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/jpamodelgen.html).

What is the best way to incorporate annotation processing into the java plugin?

I currently have the following task defined, but it has a task dependency on compileJava which will fail because some of the code is dependent on the classes that are generated by the annotation processor.

```
task processAnnotations(type: Compile) {
    genDir = new File("${projectDir}/src/generated")
    genDir.mkdirs()
    source = ['src/java']
    classpath = sourceSets.test.compileClasspath
    destinationDir = genDir
    options.compilerArgs = ["-proc:only"]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why `processAnnotations` depends on `compileJava` is that you put the test compile class path on the former task's compile class path, and the test compile class path contains the compiled production code (i.e. output of `compileJava`).

As to how to best solve the problem at hand, you shouldn't need a separate compile task. The Java compiler can invoke annotation processors and compile their generated sources (along with the original sources) in one pass (see [Annotation Processing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#processing)). One thing you'll need to do is to put the annotation processor on the compile class path:

```
configurations {
    hibernateAnnotationProcessor
}

dependencies {
    hibernateAnnotationProcessor "org.hibernate: ..."
}

compileJava.compileClasspath += configurations.hibernateAnnotationProcessor
```

(You don't want to add the annotation processor to the `compile` configuration because then it will be considered a dependency of the production code.)

From what I can tell, this is all there is to it (assuming you are using JDK6 or higher).

Comment: I went down the path of a single task, but I got an invalid flag -s error when compiling. So I kept it as a separate task. But the information you provided helped a lot. Thanks.

Comment: This partially worked for me.  I also had to tell the compiler about my processor using something like this: `compileJava.options.compilerArgs = ["-processor", "fully.qualified.processor.path.MyProcessor"]`

Answer (score 6):

Here is simple setup that works and integrates seamlessly with netbeans. Javac will basicly do all the job needed without much intervention. The rest are small treaks that will make it work with IDEs like Netbeans.

```
apply plugin:'java'

dependencies {
    // Compile-time dependencies should contain annotation processors
    compile(group: 'org.hibernate...', name: '...', version: '...')
}

ext {
    generatedSourcesDir = file("${buildDir}/generated-sources/javac/main/java")
}

// This section is the key to IDE integration.
// IDE will look for source files in both in both
//
//  * src/main/java
//  * build/generated-sources/javac/main/java
//
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
            srcDir generatedSourcesDir
        }
    }
}

// These are the only modifications to build process that are required.
compileJava {
    doFirst {
        // Directory should exists before compilation started.
        generatedSourcesDir.mkdirs()
    }
    options.compilerArgs += ['-s', generatedSourcesDir]
}
```

And that's it. Javac will make the rest of the job.

Answer (score 1):

As of gradle 4.6 you simply need to define the dependency of your processor in the appropriate configuration:

```
dependencies {
    ...

    annotationProcessor 'org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:4.3.7.Final'
}
```

Ref: https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html#added-annotationprocessor-configurations