# Gradle and standard Java tools

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Is there a standard way to have Gradle add a jar to do annotations processing?  Why isn't this built into Gradle as opposed to doing something hack-ish

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What annotation processing library are you referring to?

Comment: AndroidAnnotations right now, I have found a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351168/gradle-annotations-flavors-wont-run-annotations-processor), but I just think that Gradle should support this properly.

Comment: That would have to be a concern of the Android plugin and not Gradle core. I think it would be best to raise this issue on the Google Android forum.